# predicate logic negation laws, two quantifiers

Tags: predicate-logic

Is $\lnot\, \forall\ x\exists\, y \lnot\ P(x,y)$ equivalent to $\exists\, x \exists yP(x,y)$ ?

I understand the negation rule, I just need to make sure i got it right. help please

Answer (score 1):

We have to proceed by step :

> $¬∀x \ ∃y \ ¬P(x,y)$

is equivalent to :

> $∃x \ ¬ ∃y \ ¬P(x,y)$

which in turn is equivalent to :

> $∃x \ ∀y \ P(x,y)$.

Comment: ,, hmmmm I see. thank you